# Phaser timer don't change position object, only value of position

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine, phaser-framework

I'm creating a game with Phaser. When the user pushes the down arrow I want to change the physics size of the character, and then after 1 second return size.

I wrote code that works, but the character falls off screen, because he's in an object. So I need to pull up him and change physics size.

With this code

```
else if (this.cursors.down.isDown) {
    this.jim.body.setSize(226, 150, 0, 0);
    this.timerCrouch= this.game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 1.25, jimСrouch, this);
    this.timerCrouch.timer.start();
}

function jimСrouch() {  
    this.jim.body.setSize(226, 285, 0, 0);
    this.jim.body.y = this.jim.body.y + 150;
};
```

Character does not pull up, but in log value of `jim.body.y` change, and returns to before.

How to fix, that?
Thank you!

Comment: I gave a go at trying to clean up your question. Have you tried enabling debugging on the objects to see where the actual bounding boxes are? You never move `jim` back (`jim.body.y` is constantly moving down). I also think that instead of moving the actual sprite, you could just change the size of the bounding box instead. See http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/offset-bounding-box for an example. Crouching? Then the collision box is just the bottom half of the character's sprite, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be because of `this.cursors.down.isDown`. I don't believe that's syntactically correct because `down.isDown` is redundant.

In my game, I use `game.input.onDown.add(functionName);` and it works fine.

Comment: Actually, `this.cursors.down.isDown` is okay, as long as `cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();`. If it is, then that will return true if the <kbd>down</kbd> key is currently pressed down.